# Prove $\ker(\pi) = I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am working on some exercises and I need some assistance. The exercise goes like this:

> Prove that the kernel of the surjective homomorphism $\pi : A \rightarrow A/I$, $a \mapsto a + I$, where $I \unlhd A $ is an ideal, is $\ker(\pi) = I$.

By the definition of the kernel, it is the set of elements $a\in A$ such that $\pi(a) = I$, therefore, it is the set of all elements, $a + I = I$.

I can't seem to find what leads to $\ker(\pi) = I$. How do I find it?

Kind regards.

Comment: You got $a+I=I$. That means $a\in I$.

Comment: And that implies  $\ker(\pi) = I$?

Comment: You have a mistake there. You do not need $\pi (a) = I$,  just $\pi (a) \in I$.

Comment: Guenterino, I guess that makes it easier, elements $a$ such that $\pi(a) \in I$, ie.  $a \in I \Rightarrow \ker(\pi) = I$. Right?

Comment: Actually, the $\pi(a)=I$ condition is correct, since technically $\pi(a)$ is a coset. We have $\pi(a)=I$ if and only if $a\in I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a\in A$. Then $\pi(a)=0$ if and only if $a-0=a\in I$, so $\ker \pi=I$.

Comment: He writes $0$ for the additive identity element, which is $I$ in $A/I$. It is just different notation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How would the iff statement differ if we had the notation $\pi(a) = I$? Iff. a - I = I? ie. $a\in I$?